# Obscuring/detecting changes to a digital photograph

Tags: forensics, defense, detection

Note: I'm asking this here because it seems to be a better fit for security than for photography, since it deals with data manipulation and forensics.

With so much of our modern security based on camera stills or footage, and many security systems relying on digital photography (e.g., digital checking), there's obviously a huge need for confidence in those images being unaltered. Having a background in graphic design, I know how stupidly easy it is to alter photographs and video so that no one can tell with a naked eye they aren't real.

Having said that, I'm aware there are some basic techniques for detecting amateur changes, like drastically altering the image contrast to look for artifacts. I haven't experimented with this at all, but I'm betting there are easy ways to hide from that, like using better blending techniques or applying a slight Gaussian blur to the image.

So my question is this: **What are the most common or effective techniques for illicitly altering digital photographs** (we'll ignore video for simplicity), **and what methods/software are used for detecting them?**

Comment: Have you done any research at http://fotoforensics.com/ ?

Comment: Wow I had no idea that site existed, thanks for the link!

Comment: If you find answers in your research, it would be appreciated it if you summarized them here.  Link-only answers are frowned upon in StackExchange (they can expire), which is why I provided the link in the comments instead of as an answer.

Comment: That's definitely a good start and I've learned a lot from investigating that site, but I know there's a lot more info out there so I'm going to keep researching and see if anyone else has anything to contribute here in the meantime. If nobody does in the next few days I'll write up my own answer.

Comment: The "most common or effective techniques" of photo alteration are actually mutually exclusive, i.e., the most common techniques are the least effective by definition, because detection methods are based on knowledge of known techniques. The best methods for detection are thus likewise closely guarded secrets, because they encode the set of alteration methods which are no longer effectively clandestine.

Comment: @ruief Common knowledge doesn't necessarily make something less secure (though I can't speak specifically to photo manipulation on that). Take asymmetric encryption for example, you can look up exactly how it works, but it will still take extreme cost to break even the most common methods. In fact the more public a method is, the more likely people will attempt to crack it and thus find flaws which can be fixed.

Comment: @thanby Cryptography is a very special case, because of the concept of the secret key. Techniques for deception, and military technology categories having to do with detection and evasion, generally follow the pattern of secrecy which I described. A thought experiment should suffice here: If I tell you the method I use to detect image alterations, you can modify your alteration technique to evade my detection. There is no separation of "secret" and "non secret" components in these techniques, such as the separation between cryptographic algorithm and key material.